# Lua inheritance example creates singular instance

Tags: inheritance, lua, singleton

Let's try out the [inheritance example](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html) from the official lua docs and declare everything this way:

```lua
Account = {
  balance = 50,
  receipt = function(self)
    print(self.balance)
  end,

  new = function(self, o)
    local o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
  end
}

SpecialAccount = {
  balance = 150,  
  special_receipt = function(self)
    print(self.balance)
    print("This is special!")
  end,  
}

-- Test ---------------------------
s = Account:new(SpecialAccount)

print(tostring(Account))
print(tostring(SpecialAccount))
print(tostring(s))

s:receipt()
s:special_receipt()
```

This is nice and the `receipt-`functions work as expected, but there is a problem with `s`:

[image: console output]
It looks like `s` **is** `SpecialAccount`.

They are the same tables.
This is bad, because now you can not create several instances of `SpecialAccount`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: And yes, I want the "member-functions" to be declared like this: `new = function(self,` and not like this: `function Account:new(`

Comment: you pass `SpecialAccount` as teh second param of `Account.new` what did you expect to happen? it uses the `o` provided as the base for the object.

Comment: Did you read the entire post? I need `s` to be "non-singular".#

Comment: Nitpick: The PiL *are not the official Lua docs*; it's just a book to teach you Lua. The official docs are the *Lua reference manual*. The online PiL is for an outdated Lua version (5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like s is SpecialAccount. They are the same tables.

Yes, `s` is `SpecialAccount`: `Account:new(SpecialAccount)` makes `SpecialAccount` *extend* `Account`, returning `SpecialAccount` (this should become apparent if you go through what `:new` does and how the `:` syntactic sugar works).

In Pseudocode, this might look as follows in a language supporting class-based OOP:

```java
class Account { ... } // Account = ...
class SpecialAccount { ... } // SpecialAccount = ...
SpecialAccount extends Account; // s = Account:new(SpecialAccount)
```

Why return `SpecialAccount` you may wonder? To make it read more naturally, as in a class-based language:

```java
class SpecialAccount extends Account { ... }
```

you would write:

```lua
SpecialAccount = Account:new{
  balance = 150,  
  special_receipt = function(self)
    print(self.balance)
    print("This is special!")
  end,  
}
```

It may be considered dirty to "overload" `:new` both for instantiation and inheritance, but if you look closely, inheritance can be seen as a special form of instantiation.

> This is bad, because now you can not create several instances of `SpecialAccount`

This is incorrect. You can create an instance of `SpecialAccount` just like you can create an instance of `Account`: By calling `:new`:

```lua
s = SpecialAccount:new() -- creates a new special account
assert(s ~= SpecialAccount)
```

you can also pass a table with some values if you like:

```lua
s = SpecialAccount:new{balance = 50}
```

Comment: Oh yes! That's it! All I had to change was `SpecialAccount = Account:new{`. Thank you so much, LMD! I've tested this. It works!